# Why change background color javascript not working?

Tags: javascript

```js
function changeColor(){
var box = document.getElementById("size");
box.style.background-color ="yellow";
}
```

```css
#size{
width: 100px;
height:100px;
transition: all 1s;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: pink;" id="size" onclick="changeColor()">
</div>
```

I am learning javascript and i am at very basic level. I am making a javascipt function when user click on div it changes color. But even this simple piece of code is not working. Please help where i have committed the problem. Thank you

Comment: Open devtools and read nice error message. Then remember that `background-color` is invalid property name.

Comment: how can i open dev tools? please tell me

Comment: See CSS property list in Javascript - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference

Comment: With most browser you can open dev tool by pressing F12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

`box.style.backgroundColor ="yellow";`

Comment: And may I add https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference

Comment: Thank you for the link. very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `box.style.background-color ="yellow";`

to `box.style.backgroundColor ="yellow";`

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference) for full list of properties

```js
function changeColor(){
var box = document.getElementById("size");
box.style.backgroundColor ="yellow";
}
```

```css
#size{
width: 100px;
height:100px;
transition: all 1s;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: pink;" id="size" onclick="changeColor()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the property as a string inside `[]`:

```js
function changeColor(){
var box = document.getElementById("size");
box.style["background-color"] ="yellow";
}
```

```css
#size{
width: 100px;
height:100px;
transition: all 1s;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: pink;" id="size" onclick="changeColor()">
</div>
```